# Monero wallet balance still zero after transfer

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, transaction-confirmation, balance

As a setup test, a friend has attempted to send me 0.3 Monero to my Monero Wallet.

My Wallet was offline at the time.

I have started the server using *./monerod --offline* and running *./monero-wallet-cli*

On typing balance, the number of coins is still zero.

Questions:

1. If setup is correct, typically how long before the coins should arrive?
2. Would there be any issue with my server and wallet being offline at the time?
3. if the coins don't arrive, is there anyway I can trace this from my end? What information from my friend do I need to trace?
4. Is there any issue running with the *./monerod* daemon with the *--offline* command

Comment: When I type refresh into the wallet, I get a "Error: refresh failed: internal error: Index out of bounds of hashchain. Blocks received: 0 Background refresh thread started "   error. Looks like I have this bug https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4087/commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If setup is correct, typically how long before the coins should arrive?

One to five minutes.

> Would there be any issue with my server and wallet being offline at the time?

As long as the daemon (`monerod`) is synced through the date/time of the transaction, then it doesn't need to be online when using `monero-wallet-cli` to refresh your wallet's balance.

> if the coins don't arrive, is there anyway I can trace this from my end? What information from my friend do I need to trace?

Transaction ID's are public, so he/she can provide you that.  You could then use a block explorer like xmrchain.net or moneroblocks.info to verify the transaction is recorded in the blockchain.  On certain block explorers, you can input your address and private view key and it'll show you which outputs were sent to your address.

> Is there any issue running with the ./monerod daemon with the --offline command

Taking into account my answer to your second question, no, there's no issue. (Well, that's assuming you don't need to send Monero. If you do need to send, then you should probably not run in `--offline` mode when you generate the transfer, though I think you don't technically *have* to be online).

> On typing balance, the number of coins is still zero.

I recommend typing `status` into the daemon to verify the extent to which it has synced.  I would also verify the transaction sent to you is in fact recorded in the blockchain (and at what block).

Comment: OP claims "My Wallet was offline" at the time the tx was sent and afterwards.  So "is synced through the date/time of the transaction" criteria is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

`monerod` needs to download the block containing the transaction in order to show you the balance.  If it was offline when the transaction was sent (and stayed offline), it will not show the balance as credited to your wallet.